# Is there a way to execute free form query from a file in sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hadoop2, sqoop2

Have executed a similar kind of sqoop command as shown below. The free form query mentioned below, I wanted to keep it in a file and run the sqoop command since my real time queries are quite complex and bigger.

Wanted to know, Is there a way to keep the query in a file and execute the sqoop command which will refer the free form query inside the file and execute?
like we do for --password-file case. Thanks in advance.

```
sqoop  import --connect "jdbc:mysql://<localhost>:port" --username "admin" --password-file "<passwordfile>" --query "select * from employee" --split-by employee_id --target-dir "<target directory>" --incremental append --check-column employee_id --last-value 0 --fields-terminated-by "|"
```

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it using shell script where you will be reading the query file and pass it as the variable.

Comment: Thanks @SandeepSingh I'm achieving my requirement in the same way. But, Just wanted to know if we have something from sqoop itself to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line options that are not convenient to put in command, can be read using the Sqoop`--options-file`  argument for convenience, hence you can read the query using the options file. Using options file the Sqoop command should be similar to this:

`sqoop import --connect $connect_string --username $username --password $pwd --options-file /home/user/sqoop_poc/query.txt  --target-dir $target_dir --m 1`

Entry in options file should be like this:

`--query
select * from TEST_OPTION where ID <= 10  AND $CONDITIONS`

More details on options file are available in [Sqoop User Guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_using_options_files_to_pass_arguments).

Comment: Thanks @sandeep singh this will do help me. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @CodingOwl - Can you please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Accepted bro :)